# When I compare Character in java, Why is equals() not working, but == is?

Tags: java, character, equals

I'm trying to solve the classic **Valid Parentheses** question on LeetCode.

This is what I did, and it can pass all the test cases:

```
public boolean isValid(String s) {
    Deque<Character> stack = new LinkedList<>();
    for (Character c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (c.equals('{') || c.equals('[') || c.equals('(')) {
            stack.push(c);
        } else {
            Character check = stack.isEmpty() ? ' ' : stack.pop();
            if (check != (c - 1) && check != (c - 2)) { //***
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return stack.isEmpty();
}
```

but when I change the line *** into this:

```
if (!check.equals(c - 1) && !check.equals(c - 2)) {}
```

Although it can pass the compiler, but it can not return the right answer, not even the simple input like "()".

Normally, shouldn't we are supposed to use equals() rather than == to compare Character?

Comment: by using c-1 and c-2, you convert char to int, so it will return the int value (or ASCII) value. You cant use equals on int because it is primitive. Thus you use == because oneside is character, the other is int.

Comment: what is your input?

Comment: you could however consider explicitly casting it back to char.

Comment: @TanYuHauSean Yes, it works if I do this `if (!check.equals((char)(c - 1)) && !check.equals((char)(c - 2)))`

Comment: @TanYuHauSean Actually, yes, you can, because auto-boxing. But `equals` takes an `Object` and that expression is an `int`, so it will be boxed into `Integer` - which are not equal with `Character`s.

Comment: @ScaryWombat The original code with "=="can pass all the LeetCode test cases, but the "equals()" one, can't even pass the input like "()".

Comment: subtracting an int from a Character will return an int value.  You need to cast it back as char when using `equals` as it will be auto-boxed as an `Integer`

Comment: Also: I'm not convinced that comparing `check` with `(char)(c - 1)` and `(char)(c - 2)` is an appropriate thing to do ... in a solution to the "Valid Parentheses" problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add debugging to the if block in question

```
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(c -1);
System.out.println(c -2);
```

you will see the char followed by two int values.

In your original code, type casting was taking place.

In my IDE, there is even a warning

**Unlikely argument type for equals(): int seems to be unrelated to Character**

As summed up in the comments above:

*subtracting an int from a Character will return an int value. You need to cast it back as char when using equals as it will be auto-boxed as an Integer*